# Overwriting CORS configuration

Tags: java, rest, cors, liferay, jax-rs

I've deployed an OSGi module based on [Blade CLI blade.rest](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-gradle/blade.rest) sample and modified it to return a response instead of plain text. Here is the class:

```
package com.autentia.api.rest.users;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;


import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/users")
@Component(
        immediate = true, property = {"jaxrs.application=true"},
        service = Application.class
)
public class UsersRestService extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return Collections.singleton(this);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getUsers(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
        String json = "{\n" + "  \"value\": \"ok\"\n" + "}";
        return Response
                .status(200)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .entity(json)
                .build();
    }
}
```

(This works locally if I remove `.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`.)

The problem arise when I make a petition to the server the response has two Access-Control-Access-Origin properties, one set to "*" (Which is what I want) and one set to the ip where it has been sent. The response is as follows:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:19
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 12 Apr 2017 15:23:38 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=CF771CD0FAECDAF226D153FB05875CC3; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-URL:http://localhost:8080/o/api/users
X-XSS-Protection:1
```

As you can see there are two Access-Control-Allow-Origin which is not accepted. Where should I start looking? Should I modify Tomcat's web.xml? I've looked over `portal.properties` and `system.properties` but I haven't seen a property that enables that header.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a `CorsFilter` filter in your `CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter has the documentation.

To allow requests from any origin, you can add this to that file:

```xml
<init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: I've applied the filter mentioned in that link to Liferay's web.xml and the problem persists. Two properties Access-Control-Allow-Origin are sent to the client, which is not allowed.

Comment: I meant to look for it in that file and remove it if you found it there. But now that you’ve added it there, you could just remove the headers call from your application code, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I tried but then the only header sent is the one with the host and not *.

Comment: So then, sounds like you want to set  `<init-param><param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name><param-value>*</param-value</init-param>`?

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! What I'm trying to accomplish is to set up a public API Rest and connect to it using fetch from a remote client. Is there a better way to do that or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no better way to do it if the API is meant to accept cross-origin requests. In that case the only right way to do it is by configuring the server to send the right Access-Control-* headers. In the old days there was some value in supporting JSONP as an alternative but IMHO for any new deployments, using JSONP would be an anachronism

Comment: Added the init-param to the filter. It's still sending the wrong header :( I guess I'll have to look more thoroughly the web.xml filter. At least I know I'm headed in the right direction. I'll update the post when I find the answer. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As [@sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) mentioned the key was to edit the `web.xml` file located on the embedded Tomcat of Liferay. The configuration I applied was the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:49227</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

After that I removed the header from the response of the method `getUsers` I was using and restarted Tomcat so the configuration gets applied.

If I wanted to allow all origins or whitelist IPs I would have to change the following `param`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>http://<IP_TO_WHITELIST>:<PORT></param-value>
</init-param>
```

Or allow all origins:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
```